# how to make text alignment using position absolute

Tags: html, css

[image]

hello, Please see image, i have to make red box text aligned with "my heading", right now i have fixed this manually but when i resize the window it's going outside.

I know i can make it align if i do not use position absolute but its necessary to use position absolute because i have to call this section dynamically on each page.

so what should i do for this ??

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


<style type="text/css">

body{
    margin:0px;
}

.name-list{
        position: absolute;
    right: 167px;

}

.name-list ul{
    list-style: none; padding-left: 0px;

}

.name-list ul li{
    float: left; padding-right: 10px;
    background:red; color: white;
}

.box{
    background:#38383d; padding: 10px; float: right; color: white; width:20%;
}

</style>    


</head>
<body>

<div class="name-list">
<ul>
    <li >Name</li>
    <li>Surname</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="box">


<br>

<h2>My Heading</h2>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are asking. Please improve your question.

Comment: i am asking that i have to make align red box text with "my heading".

Comment: but by using position absolute its going outside like image when i resize the window. so how to fix that . and i have to call this dynamically so i can not put this in particular div

Comment: You trying to making relation between two independent element even which have no same parent except body and their content is dynamic. So it is hard or impossible to make alignment based their inside content. It is possible only if JS allow to manipulate them.

Comment: okay can you please tell me how it will by js, i can use that also for this

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin:0px;
    }
    
    .name-list{
            position: absolute; 
    }
    .name-list ul{
        list-style: none; padding-left: 0px;
     }
    .name-list ul li{
        float: left; padding-right: 10px;
        background:red; color: white;
    }
    .box{
        background:#38383d; padding: 10px; float: right; color: white; 
    }
    </style>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
         
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="name-list">
    <ul>
        <li >Name</li>
        <li>Surname</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <h2>My Heading</h2>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change your html the best route would be to use percentages to place and size your `.name-list`

I've got the best results with this code:

```
.name-list{
    position: absolute;
    right: 3%;
    width:18%

}
```

Code snippet:

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
}

.name-list{
    position: absolute;
    right: 3%;
    width:18%
}

.name-list ul{
    list-style: none; 
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.name-list ul li{
    float: left; 
    padding-right: 10px;
    background:red; 
    color: white;
}

.box{
    background:#38383d; 
    padding: 10px; 
    float: right; 
    color: white; 
    width:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="name-list">
  <ul>
    <li >Name</li>
    <li>Surname</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <br>
  <h2>My Heading</h2>
</div>
```

Unfortunately that's the best I can do without tinkering with your html.

Comment: No, actually I can't put this into box div because it will call dynamically on each page.

Comment: that is main problem

Comment: In that case use percentages. Updating my answer now

Comment: @ShubhamShrivastava did that get you close to where you wanted to be?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0px;
}

.name-list{
        position: absolute; 
}
.name-list ul{
    list-style: none; padding-left: 0px;
 }
.name-list ul li{
    float: left; padding-right: 10px;
    background:red; color: white;
}
.box{
    background:#38383d; padding: 10px; float: right; color: white; width:20%;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
<div class="name-list">
<ul>
    <li >Name</li>
    <li>Surname</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<h2>My Heading</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry but i can put this in to box div. because i have call this dynamically on each page

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


<style type="text/css">

body{
    margin:0px;
}

.name-list{
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
}

.name-list ul{
    list-style: none; padding-left: 0px;

}

.name-list ul li{
    float: left; padding-right: 10px;
    background:red; color: white;
}

.box{
    padding: 10px; float: right; color: white; width:250px;
}
.custom {background:#38383d;display: inline-flex;float: right;position: relative; }
</style>    


</head>
<body>
<div class='custom'>
    <div class="name-list">
        <ul>
            <li >Name</li>
            <li>Surname</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <br>
        <h2>My Heading</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but i can put this in to box div. because i have call this dynamically on each page

Comment: I edit that code again can you please check.. I think this will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

use these css to get your result, hope this will helpful to you.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.name-list {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
}

.name-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.name-list ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.box {
  background: #38383d;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  width: 20%;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="box">
<div class="name-list">
<ul>
    <li >Name</li>
    <li>Surname</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<h2>My Heading</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```